# Variance of Portfolio of Assets

Tags: covariance, descriptive-statistics

The variance of a portfolio of two assets is calculated as

$Var(R_P)=w_a^2\sigma_a^2+w_b^2\sigma_b^2+2w_aw_b\sigma_{ab}$,

where $w_a,w_b$ are the respective weights of the two assets in the portfolio and $w_a+w_b=1$.

$\sigma_a$, $\sigma_b$: individual asset standard deviations (S.D.),

$\sigma_{ab}$: covariance between assets a and b

Let us take an example. Let $w_a=0.4$ and $w_b=0.6$, $\sigma_a=12.93\%$, $\sigma_b=8.21\%$ and $\sigma_{ab}=18.6\%$.

So, is $Var(R_P)=0.4^2\times12.93^2+0.6^2\times 8.21^2+2\times 0.4\times 0.6\times 18.6 = 59.94$

Hence, the S.D of the portfolio = $7.742\%$

This way is used in Principles of Corporate Finance (Brealey, Myers)

or should it be $Var(R_P)=0.4^2\times0.1293^2+0.6^2\times 0.0821^2+2\times 0.4\times 0.6\times 0.186 = 0.0938 $

Hence, the S.D of the portfolio = $0.3072 = 30.72\%$

This is used in 
CFA Institute(www.cfainstitute.org/learning/products/publications/inv/Documents/investments_chapter5.pptx) Slide 16/35

The two answers will be different. Subsequently, the portfolio standard deviation will differ even more for the above two ways.

I seek help to find which one is the correct way and why ?

Thanks.

EDIT: I prefer the second one as both the weights and the S.D.s are in decimals .. whereas in the first one, weights are in decimals and the S.D.s are taken at the "face value" of the percentage .. this seems inconsistent .. but our prof is adamant on using the first one .. because that way ensures that the SD < variance .. whereas the second way gives higher SD (square root of a fraction is higher) .. What is the correct way here ?

Comment: The top one uses percentages and the bottom one uses decimals.  In the first one, Variance is quoted as % and in the second one variance is quoted in decimals.  That is all to it.  As the other responer, it is quite safe to use the second one as everything is in decimals.

Comment: I prefer the second one as both the weights and the S.D.s are in decimals .. whereas in the first one, weights are in decimals and the S.D.s are taken as the "face value" of the percentage .. this seems inconsistent .. but our prof is adamant on using the first one .. because the one way ensures that the SD < variance .. whereas the second way gives higher SD (square root of a fraction is higher) .. What is the correct way here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

Let us look at it differently.

When used as a percentage let us compute correlation coefficient.

$\rho = \frac{18.6}{12.93\times8.21} = .17521$

When used as decimals (as is) let us compute correlation coefficient.

$\rho = \frac{.186}{.1293\times.0821} = 17.521$

$\rho$ can never be more than 1.  While this said, let us deeply investigate this

We also know that correlation coefficient is dimensionless.  So Covariance is $\rho$ multiplied by two standard deviations.

When putting everything in decimal, you may have to divide covariance by the order of 10000. Not 100.

If you are representing everything in decimals the correct way is

$Var(R_P)=0.4^2\times0.1293^2+0.6^2\times 0.0821^2+2\times 0.4\times 0.6\times 0.00186 =0.005994$

$S.D = .0774 = 7.74$

Check out CFA website and make sure they say the covariance in percentage should be divided by 10000.

Your prof is spot on

Your example is also misleading, Covariance will not be  mentioned  percentages.  Even in your CFA slide, it is given to be 0.0050 not as 50%.  Quoting that would mislead everyone.  CFA is also correct.  Just in case Covariance is mentioned as a whole number, divide it by 10000.

Sorry for misleading earlier.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort .. such a simple thing can get twisted so fast .. :P

Comment: You bet!!.  Good luck on your CFA exams

Answer (score 0):

Although both differ only in magnitude when doing mathematical calculations you usually represent the X% as $X/100$. I suggest to use second one.

Comment: I prefer the second one as both the weights and the S.D.s are in decimals .. whereas in the first one, weights are in decimals and the S.D.s are taken as the "face value" of the percentage .. this seems inconsistent .. but our prof is adamant on using the first one .. because the one way ensures that the SD < variance .. whereas the second way gives higher SD (square root of a fraction is higher) .. What is the correct way here ?

Comment: The correct way is to use decimal points